# What's the dimension of this vectorspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the concatenation operator, e.g. $(1,2)+(3,4)=(1,2,3,4)$. With the conceit that adjacent numbers can "cancel out", e.g. $(1,2)+(-2,3)=(1,3)$, this is a group.

We can make it a vectorspace by the standard componentwise multiplication: $cx=(cx_1,cx_2,\dots)$.

Note that any element in this vector space can be written as $\sum_i c_i(1)$ for some $c_i$.

I'm wondering if this means that this vector space has dimension one, since a basis seems to be $\{(1)\}$? I have read that a vector space with a field $F$ and dimension $n$ is isomorphic to $F^n$ which would mean that my vectorspace is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$, which I don't think is true.

Comment: Could you describe more precisely how the composition works and what elements cancel which ones?

Comment: How is it a group? What would be the identity (seeing as 0s seems to disappear)? How do you construct inverses, if you just stick the tuples together?

Comment: This appears to be the [free group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group) on $\mathbb{N}$, with a peculiar operator $c$ that sends $a_1a_2\cdots a_k$ to $(ca_1)(ca_2)\cdots (ca_k)$.  I don't believe this is a vector space however.

Comment: @vadim123 Yeah, that seems right. So since it is not an abelian group, it cannot become a vector space of course.

Comment: hmm good point. And if if we declared it to be unchanged by permutations (e.g. $(1,2)=(2,1)$) to make it abelian, would it then be isomorphic to $\mathbb R$?

Comment: In that case, it is the free abelian group of countable rank. The multiplication then corresponds to the one obtained by tensoring with a field, and it gives a vector space of countable dimension (so no, it will not be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @Tobias: Why doesn't it have dimension one then? (Or is that what you mean by "countable" dimension?) Doesn't $\{(1)\}$ span the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a vector space. Vadim123 and Tobias Kildetoft already pointed out that the underlying additive group is not abelian. Also in a vector space the axiom
$$
(a+b)X=aX+bX
$$
is required to hold for all scalars $a,b$ and vectors $X$. But here if $X=(1,2)$, $a=3$, $b=4$, then
$$
(a+b)X=7X=(7,14)\qquad\text{but}\qquad aX+bX=(3,6)+(4,8)=(3,6,4,8).
$$
Allowing permutations won't help.